# How to give two user permission in same directory (linux)

Tags: linux, users

I need to give permission for two users in the same directory, ie

I'm running a web application in /var/www and I want to make web server(nginx) writable, also want to give access to a ftp user(/var/www is the home directory of ftp user). I have tried with setfacl but that doesn't work?

Comment: What OS are you running on? setfacl has some problems on Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

1. (optionally) create a group `groupadd groupname`
2. add both users to the group `for u in user1 user2 ; do usermod -aG groupname $u ; done`
3. set the group as the owner of the directory (and files inside) `chown :groupname /var/www ; chmod -R g+rwX /var/www`

Answer (score 3):

acl should work.
Are you using it right? Giving recursive rule for existing files and default for new files?

```
sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:<user-group>:rwX,g:<user-group>:rwX /var/www
```

Will give your main group rw permissions on files and x on the directories (to enter them).

```
-R: recursive
-m: modify existing rule (used to modify the existing permissions)
d:g:...:rwX: this indicates the default part for new files/directories
g:..:rwX: group to use for the acl
rwX: read, write and change directory allowed (rwx will allow execute on files too)
```

The command has two parts: `d:g:.....` before the `,` and `g:....` after the `,`
The 1st one (`d:...`) will assign the default for new files/directories and the 2nd one (`g:...`) will modify existing files.

Obs: you can also use acl for users (with u:) or other (o:) instead of groups (g:)

Comment: It worked for me but only when I removed d: